# How can I toggle the class of all elements in a selection?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to write a function that adds a class to all elements in a selection when those elements do not have that class yet, and vice versa:

```
function toggleLinksActivity(d) {
  d3.selectAll(".link")
    .filter(l => l.target == d)
    .classed("non-active", l => !l.classed("non-active"));
}
```

This gives an error that `.classed` is not a function. The [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_classed) states that `.classed` should be called on a selection, so I tried changing the last line into `!d3.select(l).classed("non-active")`, but that does not work either ("t.getAttribute is not a function"). What is going wrong and what is the correct way?

**Note:** I have already solved my problem with the 2 separate functions underneath, but I find it ugly to split a toggle into 2 parts.

```
function activateLinks(d) {
  d3.selectAll(".link")
    .filter(l => l.target == d)
    .classed("non-active", false);
}

function deactivateLinks(d) {
  d3.selectAll(".link")
    .filter(l => l.target == d)
    .classed("non-active", true);
}
```

Comment: It looks like your logic is ok -- but i suspect the filter comparison `l.target == d` is not returning anything. Hard to tell without knowing what your input `d` contains, and what `data(...)` has been attached to your links...

Comment: @SteveR I checked in the console that the filtering is done correctly.

Comment: `l` is your datum, you need to select your element to be able to class the selection properly, this is why `l.classed()` and  `d3.select(l).classed` do not work, you aren't using .classed() on a d3 selection in either approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gerardo's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50194995/4235784) is pointing in the right direction by using [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), but the proposed solution can still be simplified. As it turns out, the `classList` property already features a `.toggle()` method, which works as follows:

> **toggle( String [, force] )**
>   When only one argument is present: Toggle class value; i.e., if class exists then remove it and return false, if not, then add it and return true.
>   When a second argument is present: If the second argument evaluates to true, add specified class value, and if it evaluates to false, remove it.

Your function can thus be written as:

```
function toggleLinksActivity(d) {
  d3.selectAll(".link")
    .each(function(l) {
      if (l.target == d) {
        this.classList.toggle("non-active");
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: This is more elegant but less "d3-ish".

Answer (score 4):

You need to reselect the ith element and use its `classed` property:

```
function toggleLinkActive() {
  d3.selectAll(".link")
    .classed("non-active", (d,i,nodes) => !d3.select(nodes[i]).classed("non-active"));
}
```

You can also select `this` if you are using a non-arrow function:

```
function toggleLinkActive() {
  d3.selectAll(".link")
    .classed("non-active", function() { return !d3.select(this).classed("non-active"); });
}
```

If you want to avoid reselecting the item, you can use `each` and store the selection in a variable:

```
function toggleLinkActive() {
  d3.selectAll(".link")
    .each(function() {
      const item = d3.select(this);
      item.classed("non-active", !item.classed("non-active"));
    });
```

Or you can use the native `this.classList.toggle("non-active")` like in @altocumulus' answer.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the D3 `classed` method **again** inside itself we can use [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), toggling the class with a more short and elegant function that uses the unary negation and `contains` to check if the selection has a given class.

In my proposed function, you have to pass the selection and the name of the class. It's just this:

```
function toggleClass(selection, className) {
    selection.classed(className, !selection.node().classList.contains(className))
}
```

#### Explanation

The logic behind this function is quite simple: `contains()` returns a boolean... so, negating it (`!true` gives us `false` and `!false` gives us `true`) and passing that negated boolean to the `classed` method toggles the class in the selection.

Let's see it in action:

```js
var paragraphs = d3.selectAll("p");

d3.interval(function() {
  toggleClass(paragraphs, "foo");
  console.log(paragraphs.attr("class"))
}, 1000)

function toggleClass(selection, className) {
  selection.classed(className, !selection.node().classList.contains(className))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<p class="foo someOtherClass">Foo</p>
<p class="foo someOtherClass">Bar</p>
<p class="foo someOtherClass">Baz</p>
```